# Power to light fixture is on, light doesn't turn on

Tags: light-fixture

One of my recessed light fixtures wouldn't turn on it. Got a new fixture. New fixture doesn't turn on. Voltage detector beeps on lead going to the fixture and neutral coming out. Thought that maybe mouse chewed the wire. Attempted to bypass switch and hook directly to power. Fixture still not lighting. Voltage detector beeps on both black and white. What the heck?

[image]

Comment: 1 - Model #? 2 - Can you check the voltage between hot & neutral? 3 - "Tested with different power source and it worked" - a different circuit?

Comment: Can you check the voltage from hot to neutral, and also if there is continuity from neutral to ground with the breaker for the circuit off?

Comment: Then your problem is between the switch and the service panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Non-working fixture was last one on the run. Opened up the  fixture before it and found that the neutral to the last fixture was not connected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if the white you're connecting to is a 'permanent phase' coming from another switch, in older installation was allowed to use white as phase in switch circuits (white was permanent phase from junction box to switch and black coming out of the switch was the switched phase bringing phase to the fixture).